# Connecting to RDS Mysql from docker container with Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker, rds

Using docker-compose to spin up a wordpress container but within that container I want to connect to a RDS mysql instance on AWS. I am able to setup the wordpress but can't connect to the db. I've tried changing the DB_NAME variable to _DATABASE. I also am able to use the mysql command line from my mac to make the connection which works

```
version: '2'

services:
   wordpress:
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_HOST: "endpoint"
       MYSQL_USER: "user"
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pass"
       MYSQL_DB_NAME: "wordpress_docker"
       MYSQL_PORT: 3306
     volumes:
       - ${HOME}:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: What **Host** do you provide? The RDS instance address?

Comment: For host, I use the long endpoint
`.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to WordPress's [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/)

The environment name should be,

```
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=... (defaults to the IP and port of the linked mysql container)
WORDPRESS_DB_USER=... (defaults to "root")
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=... (defaults to the value of the MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD environment variable from the linked mysql container)
WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=... (defaults to "wordpress")
WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=... (defaults to "", only set this when you need to override the default table prefix in wp-config.php)
```

Comment: hey, did it work @Patrick? specifying endpoint:port in db_host doesn't work for me. I don't have a mysql container. It directly connects to rds.

Comment: @Satys if specifying endpoint:port WORDPRESS_DB_HOST doesn't work for you, in your case, I could say try connecting to the RDS from the machine directly. Connectivity is a common issue with RDS. Maybe, the security group is not right. Or the db user is not able to remote access.

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar challenge : https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/615. Could you share your dockerfile please ? Also, how do you specify the CA Cert for SSL please ?  PS: I am able to connect to the remote RDS instance from local desktop via MySQL workbench.